# Job Email shows me position outside my interested location

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Every time I get an email from the job section of this site, it shows me openings for positions in locations I have no interests in.

I have it set for what location I want to hear about but it's apparently ignoring that.

I have opted out of the emails until that is fixed.

Comment: Yup, this is a bug. I'm looking into it right now!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the report. We're currently in a migratory state while we prepare for Developer Story being used in Careers and match preferences are affected by this.

We had a consistency issue whereby Stack Overflow thought the data should look one way and Careers though it should look another. I've run a backfill that corrects the data anomalies and made sure your data looks good.

Sorry for the delay, I was waiting for a scheduled job to run before verifying that everything looked correct!